# Best practice for web applications and windows services remote configuration in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

we have a distributed system that contains windows services and web applications (.NET and Java based). Currently, most of the initial configuration for these applications are taken from various locations in the system and thus I wish to centralize the configuration management.
We have a bunch of EC2 instances for all of these services. I have learnt that there are Tags and Groups that can be very useful for central management of instances.

The solution can partly be development based (as we have a small team of developers that can do almost anything with AWS SDK).

Now, this is what I thought about: every server application, on its initialization, sends a request for AWS, gets its own instance ID, and sends its ID to a web API, that will be developed. The Web API would then request the **Tags** for the EC2 instance ID and retrieve the customized configuration from an RDS instance that will be raised for that purpose.

Is this a proper solution? Are there any other practices to be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is product that with the right customization does exactly what I was required:
http://www.getchef.com/solutions/aws/

Also, developing an internal system DB would work and is not a big issue.